# How to get the request header sent by requests.get()?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'd like to know what a HTTP GET request header is sent by `requests.get()` from the client side.

```
requests.get('http://localhost:9000')
```

The request header sent by the above python command monitored by `netcat` is the following. However, I don't find a way to directly monitor the HTTP GET request header sent at the client side.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9000
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/2.18.4
```

```
import requests
import sys
req = requests.Request('GET', 'localhost:9000')
print req.headers

prepared = req.prepare()

s = requests.Session()
page = s.send(prepared)
```

The request header sent by the above python command monitored by netcat is the following.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9000
Accept-Encoding: identity
```

Also, `req.headers` can be used to monitor the header. It is not exactly the same as the header sent as it does not contain the `Accept-Encoding` header. Also, the HTTP GET request header sent by this way is also different from that of the first way.

```
$ ./main.py
{}
```

Is there a method to directly monitor what HTTP GET header is sent in the first way?

Also, why the requests send by the two methods are not the same? Isn't it better to make them consistent to avoid possible confusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to know what a HTTP GET request header is sent by `requests.get()` from the client side

If I got it right, you want to view headers, that were actually sent by `requests.get()`.

You can access them by using `.request.headers` attributes:

```py
import requests

r = requests.get("http://example.com")
print(r.request.headers)
```